# antenna matching with lumped elements

Tags: rf, antenna, transmission-line, impedance-matching

Is there any resources online that describe how to match antenna elements to a TX line with a lumped element matching network?  I've got a 50 ohm load and a TX line that i'm trying to match to a 2.4GHz chip antenna...

Some research online shows that this antenna can vary around 50ohms and the PCB i'm reworking has 0402 pads available in a 5-element Chebychev filter arrangement.

I have a network analyzer 10MHZ to 6GHZ from HP.

So, the antenna is around but probably not exactly 50ohms, the microstrip is at 50ohms characteristic, and the chip has a balun inside the port, but the datasheet promises that it's 50ohms (which I don't understand how an inductive balun can be be a real 50ohms, but that's a topic for another post).

Since I can't do any stub matching or anything with the traces, is it possible to match this with a handful of L's and C's?

Comment: Note a [very similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180424/how-do-i-impedance-match-two-complex-impedances) was asked just yesterday. Unfortunately with no answers yet (or clarification from OP about just what he wants). Hopefully your question, with more detail about the goal of the matching, will get better answers.

Comment: Certainly possible if you have a set of pads, anything is possible. What RF test equipment do you have? Can you adjust the antenna geometry?

Comment: Added the RF test equipment in an edit to the post.  I cannot adjust the antenna geometry.

Comment: Take a peek at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rahzrPdEeE8) funny yet creepy vid for a look at all of the tuning cavities and other construction details of a 10GHz transceiver. Impressive!

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.johansontechnology.com/tuning.html) as a starting point for your investigation. It shows how to perform measurements then use LC or pi network and smith chart to do matching.